# Code to run commands in string format over UART using microcontroller "Atmel32"

Tags: c, embedded, avr, uart

I'm writing code to run commands in string format (TurnONLED) over UART peripheral from a computer using terminal emulator, but the code prints only the header which is in UART_SendString function and ignores the receive part (command). I rectified the code, but still does not respond to string command only numeric commands work so the question is how to make conditional statement work with a string rather numeric values. output is attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHn0o.png)
UART Module Initialized and Active

UART>>1

UART>>2

UART>>TurnONLED

UART>>TurnOFFLED

```
#include "DIO_interface.h" 
#include "PORT_interface.h" 
#include "USART_interface.h" 
const char TurnONLED = '1';
const char TurnOFFLED = '2';

void PORT_voidInit(void); 
void USART_voidInit(void);  //baud rate: 9600  frame size to 8 bits  1 stop bit  no parity

unsigned char USART_Receive(void)        //function receives a character in Ascii
void gets_UART1(unsigned char *string);  //function concatenates characters to get a string (command) 

void main (void) 
{ 
    unsigned char Str[72]; 
    PORT_voidInit();  //Rx input (PD0) and Tx output (PD1)
    USART_voidInit();

    UART_Send_String("UART Module Initialized and Active");
    USART_voidSend('\r');          //carriage return
    UART_Send_String("UART>>");   //command console
    while(1)
    {
        gets_UART1(Str);              //get command as a string
        UART_Send_String("UART>>");   //command console 
        USART_voidSend('\n');         //line feed
        if(*Str==TurnONLED)         //data in ASCI as PC sends ASCI data
        {
            DIO_u8SetPinValue (PORTA, PIN0, PIN_HIGH);    //LED ON;
        }
        else if(*Str==TurnOFFLED)
        {
            DIO_u8SetPinValue (PORTA, PIN0, PIN_LOW);     //LED OFF;
        }
    }
}


void gets_UART1(unsigned char *string)  //Receive a character until carriage return or newline
{
     unsigned char i=0,J=0;
     do
     {
         string[i] = USART_u8Receive();
         J = string[i];
         i++;
     }
     while(J!='\r');
     string[i] = '\0';
}


unsigned char USART_Receive(void) 
{
    while(GET_BIT(UCSRA,UCSRA_RXC)==0); 
    return UDR;        //USART I/O Data Register 
}
```

Comment: The values `1` and `2` aren't the same as the characters `'1'` and `'2'`. In ASCII those character values would be 49 and 50.

Comment: Do you see the output from `UART_Send_String("UART>>");`?

Comment: Carriage return (13 or `'\r'`) is a different character than line feed (10 or `'\n'`).

Comment: For comparing strings like "TurnONLED", you should use something like `strcmp("TurnONLED", buf) == 0`. Your `gets_USART()` should also actually check the buffer size, when adding to the buffer.

Comment: Eventually, it works using "strncmp" syntax. It has to have number of characters to compare   if((strncmp(Str, ledon, 5))==0)
  {
   DIO_u8SetPinValue (PORTA, PIN0, PIN_HIGH);    //LED ON;
  }

Answer (score 0):

- `#define TurnONLED    1`  -> `const char TurnONLED = '1';`.
- `#define TurnOFFLED   2`  -> `const char TurnOFFLED = '2';`.
- `USART_voidSend(10);           //ASCII value 10 for carriage return (print a new line)` ->
  `USART_voidSend('\n');  // line feed`
- `*(string+i)` -> `string[i]`
- You need to set the data direction register corresponding to `PORTA` to outputs somewhere.
- `gets_UART1` should not stop upon encountering `\r`, it should just discard it and keep reading. Otherwise you leave a `\n` in the UART rx buffer which will mess up continuous reads or cause overrun errors.
- The last `i++;` in `gets_UART1` is incorrect and should be removed.